# Error when deserializing Json Object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Hey i am new to working with json objects need some help please. The code is in the link below and the error message is:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LaiosIntranet.ExternalApis.HarvestApi+UserAssignment]]]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

[image]

This is the json file for the UserAssignment.

> {"4812177":[{"Id":"36849769","UserId":"431187","ProjectId":"4812177","HourlyRate":300.0,"Deactivated":false,"IsProjectManager":false,"CreatedAt":"2014-01-10T17:30:24","UpdatedAt":"2014-01-10T17:30:52"},{"Id":"36849771","UserId":"234084","ProjectId":"4812177","HourlyRate":950.0,"Deactivated":false,"IsProjectManager":false,"CreatedAt":"2014-01-10T17:30:24","UpdatedAt":"2014-01-10T17:30:52"},{"Id":"36849774","UserId":"149539","ProjectId":"4812177","HourlyRate":950.0,"Deactivated":false,"IsProjectManager":false,"CreatedAt":"2014-01-10T17:30:24","UpdatedAt":"2014-01-10T17:30:52"},

This is the UserAssignment

```
 public class UserAssignment
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public double HourlyRate { get; set; }
        public bool Deactivated { get; set; }
        public bool IsProjectManager { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt  { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As the error message says; you can't serialize into an `IEnumerable`, you'll have to serialize into JSON array's, or make a custom class with proper serialization tags.

Comment: Copy your json content and paste it to http://json2csharp.com/ . This will generate you C# models which you can use later on.

Comment: give code not image...

Comment: What's your code to deserialize the JSON string?

Comment: @Kolky what do you mean? can you give me an example if it's possible.

Comment: what is "4812177"? It should be UserAssignment there

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar It's the project number where the users are assigned.

Comment: I think due to that you might be getting the error. paste your JSON in http://www.json2csharp.com and it will show invalid type.